# coupled differential equations

Tags: differential-equations

I have to solve a set of coupled differential equations. First I have created a table containing all the equations and then solved using NDsolve.

```
 equations = Table[
  I D[M1n[[i]][[j]][[k]], t] == 
   Part[(m2/(b[[i]]*(*10**)10^6*1.98*10^-10) + 
        10^5/t^4*Sum[If[l == i, 0, M1n[[l]]], {l, 1, 3, 1}]).M1n[[
       i]] - M1n[[
       i]].(m2/(b[[i]]*(*10**)10^6*1.98*10^-10) + 
        10^5/t^4*Sum[If[l == i, 0, M1n[[l]]], {l, 1, 3, 1}]), j, 
    k], {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 2}, {k, 1, 2}]
equations1 = Flatten[equations];
s1 = NDSolve[{equations1, ci, di, 
   ei}, {Flatten[{Variables[M1n[[1]]], Variables[M1n[[2]]], 
     Variables[M1n[[3]]]}]}, {t, 2.2, 10^4},
  PrecisionGoal -> 5, WorkingPrecision -> 7]
```

where,

```
  b = Array[En, 3];
En[1] = 10;
En[2] = 11;
En[3] = 15;
M1n = Table[
  Array[Subscript[Subscript[\[Rho], i], #1, #2][t] &, {2, 2}], {i, 1, 
   3}]
\[Theta] =11.53*\[Pi]/180;
m2 = 1/(2*2)*2*10^-3*{{Cos[
     2 \[Theta]], -Sin[2 \[Theta]]}, {-Sin[2 \[Theta]], -Cos[
      2 \[Theta]]}}
M0 = {{10, 10^-5}, {10^-5, 5}};
ci = Thread[Flatten[M1n[[1]]] == Flatten[M0]] /. {t -> 2};
M20 = {{10, 10^-5}, {10^-5, 4}};
di = Thread[Flatten[M1n[[2]]] == Flatten[M20]] /. {t -> 2};
M30 = {{10, 10^-5}, {10^-5, 3}};
ei = Thread[Flatten[M1n[[3]]] == Flatten[M30]] /. {t -> 2};
```

But this is showing an error

```
NDSolve::precw: The precision of the differential equation ({{I (TemporaryVariable$13055^\[Prime])[t]==TemporaryVariable$13057[t] (-0.0989128+100000 Power[<<2>>] Plus[<<2>>])-TemporaryVariable$13056[t] (-0.0989128+100000 Power[<<2>>] Plus[<<2>>]),I (TemporaryVariable$13056^\[Prime])[t]==TemporaryVariable$13056[t] (0.232347 +100000 Power[<<2>>] Plus[<<2>>])-TemporaryVariable$13055[t] (-0.0989128+100000 Power[<<2>>] Plus[<<2>>])+TemporaryVariable$13058[t] (-0.0989128+100000 Power[<<2>>] Plus[<<2>>])-TemporaryVariable$13056[t] (-0.232347+100000 Power[<<2>>] Plus[<<2>>]),<<20>>,TemporaryVariable$13065[2]==1/100000,TemporaryVariable$13066[2]==3},{},{},{},{}}) is less than WorkingPrecision (7.`). >>
NDSolve::ndsz: At t == 2.`7., step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected. >>
NDSolve::ndsz: At t == 2.`7., step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected. >>
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: Delete: " WorkingPrecision -> 7" and add: "MaxSteps -> Infinity" then your code will execute.

Comment: Yes  I tried that but now it is showing

Comment: NDSolve::dsfun: {Subscript[Subscript[\[Rho], 1], 1,1][t],Subscript[Subscript[\[Rho], 1], 1,2][t],Subscript[Subscript[\[Rho], 1], 2,1][t],Subscript[Subscript[\[Rho], 1], 2,2][t],Subscript[Subscript[\[Rho], 2], 1,1][t],Subscript[Subscript[\[Rho], 2], 1,2][t],Subscript[Subscript[\[Rho], 2], 2,1][t],Subscript[Subscript[\[Rho], 2], 2,2][t],Subscript[Subscript[\[Rho], 3], 1,1][t],Subscript[Subscript[\[Rho], 3], 1,2][t],Subscript[Subscript[\[Rho], 3], 2,1][t],Subscript[Subscript[\[Rho], 3], 2,2][t]} cannot be used as a function. >>

Answer (score 1):

Maybe we have a version problem. On Mathematica 12.1  I get 12 numerical functions, some of them with complex output. I post a plot of the first one. The rest with real output look similar.
[image]

Comment: Ok. I am using Mathematica 10.

Comment: I am using Mathematica 10.4

Comment: As you see, the result is highly oscillatory and it is well possible that version 10 is not able to do it. But I can not claim this with certainty.

Comment: I have solved the same set of equations by writing each equation separately and it is giving some solution.

Comment: s = NDSolve[{ 
   I D[M1n[[1]], 
      t] == (m2/(10*10^6*1.98*10^-10) + 
        10^5/t^4*2*(M1n[[2]] + M1n[[3]])).M1n[[1]] - 
     M1n[[1]].(m2/(10*10^6*1.98*10^-10) + 
        10^5/t^4*2*(M1n[[2]] + M1n[[3]])), 
   I D[M1n[[2]], 
      t] == (m2/(11*10^6*1.98*10^-10) + 
        10^5/t^4*2*(M1n[[1]] + M1n[[3]])).M1n[[2]] - 
     M1n[[2]].(m2/(11*10^6*1.98*10^-10) + 
        10^5/t^4*2*(M1n[[1]] + M1n[[3]])), 
   I D[M1n[[3]], 
      t] == (m2/(15*10^6*1.98*10^-10) +

Comment: 10^5/t^4*2*(M1n[[1]] + M1n[[2]])).M1n[[3]] - 
     M1n[[3]].(m2/(15*10^6*1.98*10^-10) + 
        10^5/t^4*2*(M1n[[1]] + M1n[[2]])), ci, di, ei},   Flatten[{Variables[M1n[[1]]], Variables[M1n[[2]]], 
    Variables[M1n[[3]]]}], {t, 2, 10^4}, AccuracyGoal -> 10, 
  PrecisionGoal -> 15]

Comment: Then I am not sure if it is the problem of the version.

Comment: Your code has syntax errors: look near: "(M1n[[1]] + M1n[[2]])), ci, di, ei}". If you paste  some code, always copy it again and paste it back to your computer to check if it runs.

Comment: By the way looks your solution similar to mine?

Comment: ok. thank you for the correction. yes the solution is similar to yours.